# WWW::Mechanize: Download a specific image

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm trying to download expression data for DNA sequences. On the page, the graph (a png image) is always the 6th, 7th, or 8th image on the page, but I do not want to download 2 extra images every time.

Inspecting the image on the page yields `<img src="../trash/hgc/gtexGene_genome_6d0b_5d5220.png" border="1">`, though those last few numbers in the link to the image change every time.

In my code, I have

```
my $image = $mech1->find_image( alt_regex => qr/gtexGene/i );;
$mech1->get($image -> URI);
$mech1->save_content("exp.png");
```

which is not working.

How can I download the image given only what some of the contents of its link are?

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?  How exactly is it not working?  What is it doing that you do not it expect it to do?

Comment: Please note that you seem to have two objects, `$mech1` and `$mech`.  Perhaps you have them confused?

Comment: Whoops! I made a typo typing the code in. Sorry! I expect it to download the image on the page with "gtexGene" in its link

Comment: Please don't type in your code (for exactly this reason!) Please cut and paste your code into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `alt_regex`, which is doing a pattern match on the `alt` attribute. What you want is the `src` attribute, so you need [to use `url_regex` instead](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-find_image).

> `url => 'string',` and `url_regex => qr/regex/,`
>
> Matches the URL of the image against string or regex, as appropriate. The URL may be a relative URL, like foo/bar.html, depending on how it's coded on the page.

So your code should read like this.

```
my $image = $mech->find_image( url_regex => qr/gtexGene/i );
```

Only use the `/i` modifier for case-insensitivity if you really want it to be case-insensitive.